# Access SignalR connection context in authorization attribute handler code

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-authorization

I can't get the SignalR connection context when using the Authorize attribute on a hub method.

I'm able to access the `HttpContext` from my custom Authorization attribute on my Hub:

```
[Authorize("MyAuthorizationPolicy")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
```

In my `AuthorizationHandler` I can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to get to the `HttpRequest`, which gives me access to the token (which is in the header).

But because method invocation doesn't use the `HttpRequest`, I need to get to the SignalR request context, when I apply an Authorization attribute to my *method*:

```
[Authorize("MyAuthorizationPolicy")]
public async Task Join(Guid roomGuid)
```

Obviously, my instance of `IHttpContextAccessor` gives me a null `HttpContext`. How can I inject a '`SignalRConnectionContextAccessor`'? :)

(https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/11331)

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11331#issuecomment-489670019), SignalR is decoupled with HTTP so you may not want to access HTTP context in SignalR contexts.

I do, however, have a not elegant solution for this. SignalR hub `Context` has a property `Features` of type `IFeatureCollection`, which is a dict. Do a LINQ on it:

```
var contextFeature = hub.Context.Features.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Key == typeof(IHttpContextFeature)).Value as IHttpContextFeature;
var httpContext = contextFeature?.HttpContext;
```

Remind to check null for `httpContext`.

I don't recommend this solution though. You should pass your authorization info in `User` as claims, which is accessible in hub's `Context`.